# Bad Request when trying to submit long string to Asp.Net Web Api 2 controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to check if a long string exists in a column in my database. The string contains spaces, special characters and carriage return / line feeds.

My controller looks like this

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(ReportsDTO.ReportDTO))]
    [Route("api/Reports/GetReportIfExists/Value={text}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReportIfExists(string text)
    {
        Report report = db.Reports.Where(x => x.reporttext == text).First();

        if (report == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ReportsDTO.ReportDTO reportDTO = TranslateDTO.ConvertReportToDTO(report);

        return Ok(reportDTO);
    }
```

And I called it like this

```
    static async Task<string> GetReportAsync(string reporttext)
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;

        var builder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost/myAPI/api/Reports/GetReportIfExists/Value=" + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(reporttext));
        builder.Port = -1;

        string url = builder.ToString();

        var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        return responseString;
    }
```

But the response comes back with 'Bad Request'.
The request works fine for simple strings what do not contain spaces or any other special characters.

How can I pass a complex long string to my controller?

Comment: You probably want to look at `UrlEncode` instead of `HtmlEncode` on the client side. In addition, `First` throws an exception when no items are found, it will not return `null`.

Comment: Why don't you try and send data in form data with [FromBody] instead of the URL.

Comment: @KishanVaishnav yes that's what I decided to do in the end, as my string would probably exceed the maximum allowable size limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your route seems wrong and it should rather be

```
[Route("api/Reports/GetReportIfExists/{text}")]
```

Second be aware that every browser poses restriction on length of URI and thus if your string input is very long I would suggest pass it as body of request rather

Comment: Asp.net returns 414 Request-URI Too Large for long uri by defaul, not 400. And route from the question is Ok, semantically wrong, but should works

Comment: So basically remove the {text} from my route and just call the controller with the body of the request set to my large text.  Then decode it in the controller using something like await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() ?

Answer (score 1):

Should be used [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_) instead of *WebUtility.HtmlEncode*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the route to this (removed /Value={text} )

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(ReportsDTO.ReportDTO))]
    [Route("api/Reports/GetReportIfExists")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetReportIfExists(string text)
    {

    }
```

and change called method to

```
 var builder = new UriBuilder("http://localhost/myAPI/api/Reports/GetReportIfExists?text=" + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(reporttext));
```

Because URL has limit length you may need update in web.config

```
<requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
```